# Multiple @tests but did not execute the priority 2 and priority 3

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, selenium2, testng, eclipse

Can someone let me know why it stops execute after the first @test(priority=1)? It ran the @beforeclass, then @test(priority 1) then @aftermethod. So it skipped @test(prority=2) and @test(priority=3)

```
public class SDSearchTest {

    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl= "website";
    ExtentReports report;
    ExtentTest test;

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void sdLogin() {
        //enter username and password 


    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void testDocument() throws Exception {
        //find the element 1, enter data and drag and drop 

    }
    @Test(priority=3)
    public void pheWastesting() {

       //find the element 2, enter data and drag and drop 


    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown(ITestResult testResult) throws IOException {

        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you Share the error shown on the stacktrace

Comment: Were there any exceptions thrown? You shouldn't use driver.quit(); in @AfterMethod, if you're planning to use the driver in other test methods as well.

Comment: Are you using testng.xml to run the test cases? if yes. paste the text of the testng.xml file in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing [TestNG annotations](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations) with different behavior to set up and tear down the WebDriver:

- `@BeforeClass`: Runs once before the first test method of the class.
- `@AfterClass`: Runs once after the last test method of the class.
- `@BeforeMethod`: Runs before each test method.
- `@AfterMethod`: Runs after each test method.

Change `@AfterMethod` to `@AfterClass`—just like you did with `@BeforeClass` for your setup method—on your teardown method to only quit the WebDriver when all test methods have been executed.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior, because there is a `driver.quit()` in the `@AfterMethod`.

> The purpose of `@AfterMethod` is it runs after each `@Test` method in
>   a class.

So the execution flow will be `@BeforeClass` then the `@Test` with highest priority followed by `@AfterMethod`. Here the execution will stop.

Hope this explains.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `driver.quit();` in your `@AfterMethod`. Instead you can use it in `@AfterClass`. So your execution will be as follows:

```
@BeforeClass
@Test(priority=1)
@Test(priority=2)
@Test(priority=3)
@AfterClass
```